# Why are system calls in C always error-checked?

Tags: c, system, system-calls, errno

Obviously, it's good practice. That goes without saying. I see it every time in example code (like `socket()`, `fork()`, or `malloc()`, to name a few). I know to do it, I just don't understand the why of it so much. Are they prone to failing often? Is it because system calls are made in kernel mode? What's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Well, if you don't do it and something fails and you continue all bets are off. They don't fail often in "normal" usage but when they do you want to know about it and act accordingly.

Comment: This is just a _needed practice_ to handle _ANY_ possible unexpected erroneous result you are getting. This way your program does not crash and falls gracefully.

Comment: It is called "defensive programming". Just don´t assume that everything will go as planned. Even if the failure forces the program to abort, the user needs to know it is not their fault and the debugger deserves a nice, meaningful log message.

Comment: I have a too few experience in professional development so I will not raise an answer. But, most of the time, I didn't see any checks on calls to malloc since you are mostly gonna exit your program. However. It can be pretty useful to check a malloc, fork, socket etc... to "try" to close your program properly. By example, you can close your socket on a malloc failure, which can happen if you ran out of ram. It does not happen often, but it is still possible. I already experienced that.

Comment: @Masadow, by catching the error, you avoid a segmentation fault. This way, if the program is doing anything else at the same time, it will still be able to fulfill its purpose, only the localized part where the allocation failure is critical will be aborted.

Comment: @Rerito Most of the time, if a malloc fail, you will not be able to do anything, and your program may be killed by the task manager without no reason since your computer will going crazy. I personnaly think this is a good practice to check malloc. But there are some case where it won't do anything else than making your code more beautiful

Comment: @SJuan76: I disagree slightly on the definition of "defensive programming". To me, defensive programming is writing (sometimes redundant) code to handle cases that can't (or at least shouldn't be able to) happen, to account for the fact the other parts of the code (e.g. the library or system interfaces you're using) may be buggy, or for neutrinos flipping bits or other such weirdness. Checking the return value of functions that can fail *even when properly used*, e.g. because they require resources, is simply an essential part of correct code, not "defensive programming".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you are asking why code that calls these routines checks the results to determine whether an error occurred.

Each of the routines you cite, `socket`, `fork`, and `malloc`, requires resources. Those resources may be unavailable either because the calling process has exceeded limits set by the system administrator or the user or because the system has exhausted the resources it has and cannot provide any more to processes. Therefore, it is possible, even if not frequent, that a call to one of these routines will return failure. So a calling process should check for failure.

Additionally, in some implementations, some system routines (such as `read` and `write`) can be interrupted if a signal is delivered to the process before the operation completed. (When a signal arrives, it is considered important, and it is desirable to deliver it to the process immediately rather than wait for a potentially long operation to complete. So the operation is interrupted, the signal is delivered, the process may handle the signal and return from the signal handler. Then control is returned to the code that called the original routine, and that code must be informed that the operation was interrupted.) This interruption results in returning failure with an error status indicating the operation was interrupted.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Always, if only..
Way back when as a C function could only return an integer, and exceptions were science fiction, they came up with the idea of returning either success or a code that provided a clue as to what had gone wrong. It became a convention.

Depends on what you call a failure.

Something like opening a file (given the developer can be bothered) are relatively easy to deal with, File not found for instance. Malloc, is a bit more difficult to take some remedial action.

The key point though is to check as near to the error as possible. If you don't, you find that the file you wanted to open and append to didn't exist 10,000 lines of code later, when you try and write the results of your extensive computation to it and get say an access violation.

Basically this stuff is the reason exceptions were invented. Checking the return value is "optional", swallowing an exception is explicit.

Answer (score 0):

***example:***

```
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("c:\\removedDirectory\nonexistingFile.txt", "r")//returns NULL  

if(fp != NULL)
{
    //stuff here will fail if fp == NULL

}
```

If you do not check output of fopen, *(replace with any function that returns an error)* and `fp` is NULL, the subsequent functions depending on a real file stream will not work.